# Facebook javascript SDK multiple subdomains: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a website that depends on a dynamic subdomain. (companya.MyDomain.com, companyb.MyDomain.com, etc.)

When I attempt my FB.init() call, I am getting:

> "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains."

in my javascript console.  In my facebook app settings I have the following:

- AppDomains: MyDomain.com
- Valid OAuth redirect URIs: http://MyDomain.com
- Site URL: http://www.mydomain.com

If I explicitly add the correct subdomain (companya.mydomain.com) to the Valid OAuth redirect URIs list, my call from companya.mydomain.com works (but companyb.mydomain.com doesn't).  I do not want to add all of the subdomains that are configured for my site.  These are dynamic and can change frequently.

Ideally, I'd like the ability to use *.MyDomain.com but I understand that is not supported.  Where I'm stuck is that the error message says "...or the domain must be a SUBDOMAIN of one of the App's domains."

In this scenario, I believe that is the case when I use companya.MyDomain.com or companyb.MyDomain.com

Does anyone know how I can work around this?